# How to find by ObjectId Django, MongoDB

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

How to find by ObjectId (`id` field)

```
record = Record.objects.filter(_id=id).first() -> None
record = Record.objects.get(_id=id) -> Error DoesNotExists
```

Comment: does using `pk=id` work (pk is independent of the actual name of the primary key)?